# Set Docusign signature width & height

Tags: docusignapi

I had written below code .But signature height is not changing .it is picking default height and width .What is "signHere.WidthMetadata".How to set it.

```
        SignHere signHere = new SignHere();
        signHere.DocumentId = DocumentId;
        signHere.PageNumber = PageNumber;
        signHere.RecipientId = RecipientId;
        signHere.XPosition = XPosition;
        signHere.YPosition = YPosition;``
        signHere.Width = "200px";
        signHere.Height = "200px";
```

Answer (score 1):

Width and height cannot be used on a SignHere tab. Instead use ScaleValue e.g.

```
SignHere signHere = new SignHere();
    signHere.DocumentId = DocumentId;
    signHere.PageNumber = PageNumber;
    signHere.RecipientId = RecipientId;
    signHere.XPosition = XPosition;
    signHere.YPosition = YPosition;
    signHere.ScaleValue = "2"
```

2 is the maximum value that can be used, anything higher will default to 2. You can use decimal values for anything in between i.e. ScaleValue = "1.5"